# How to GROUP BY multiple columns in a data table in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

So I looked everywhere for a possible example but it seems I am unable to find anything. So i have a datatable that i need to group by (like in a sql query), column 1,2,3,4 (Group By 1,2,3,4) and they return the results as a a new datatable. I tried multiple methods via Linq but the syntax makes no sense to me. So far This is how my table is set up.

```
aTable.Columns.Add("align_subdiv_code", GetType(String))
aTable.Columns.Add("region_nbr", GetType(Int32))
aTable.Columns.Add("district_nbr", GetType(Int32))
aTable.Columns.Add("house_nbr", GetType(Int32))
```

I need to group it by align_subdiv_code,region_nbr, district_nbr, house_nbr
(Group by 1,2,3,4), but i honestly have no idea where to start with Linq.

Comment: I have deleted my answer after reading your comment. Why are you requesting something (a LINQ method) without even knowing how to deal with it?! Shall I teach you how to deal with LINQ outputs? Do some basic learning (of how LINQ works) and please ask specific questions about specific problems on which you have a basic understanding.

Comment: you may want to check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121303/how-to-use-groupby-to-group-over-multiple-columns-with-vb-net

Comment: @DJONES This is not useful for the OP because he doesn't know how to deal with LINQ outputs. In fact, this situation is a bit complex for LINQ and, if you are not used to this format, you shouldn't even try; it is not a magical solution, but an approach which (when properly used) might deliver more efficient solutions in certain situations. With loops you can get the same than with LINQ methods; and when things get complicated (or you are not used to LINQ), you shouldn't even consider the LINQ approach (it would make you waste more time and even output less efficient/readable codes).