# Grouping by multiple columns using a BindingSource does not work

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

In entity Frameowrk 6 , i need to group by multiple columns and after find how many groups have more than 1 item.

This is my code  :

```
context.obj1s.load()

Bindingsource1.Datasource=context.obj1s.Local.Tolist

Dim q As Integer = Bindingsource1.Datasource.
                                  GroupBy(Function(x) New With {key.name=x.name, key.price=x.Price,key.lg= x.lg}).
                                  Where(Function(t3) t3.Count > 1).
                                  Count
```

I run this query against this table :

Name..........Price.......lg....Status

A.....................2...........5......nm1

A.....................2...........5......nm2

A.....................2...........5.......nm3

B.....................7...........4........tr5

I'm expecting that q=1 , but q=0.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GroupBy() to group over multiple columns with VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121303/how-to-use-groupby-to-group-over-multiple-columns-with-vb-net)

Comment: It took me seconds to find that your question had already been asked and answered on this very site, simply by searching the web for "vb.net groupby". You should not be posting a question here before searching for answers already on the web. If you can't find answers then by all means ask, but you should ALWAYS look first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have used the solution , but does not work in my case., you can try by yourself. If i use context.obj1s.gorupby... then is working , but no using Bindingsource as in my case

Comment: Then you should edit your question and add that information, showing the new code and explaining exactly what now happens.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i've already done.It happens the same thing : I'm expecting that q=1 but q=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS WORKING :**

```
Dim q As Integer = DirectCast(Bindingsource1.Datasource,Ienumerable(of obj1)).
               GroupBy(Function(x) 
               New With {key.name=x.name, key.price=x.Price,key.lg= x.lg}).
               Where(Function(t3) t3.Count > 1).Count
```

Thank you !